# La constitution stipule, établit, dispose, autre chose ?

Tags: droit-et-justice

On utilise assez souvent des phrases du types "la loi stipule" quand on veut utiliser un terme un peu technique, mais ça fait hurler les juristes parce que seul un contrat peut stipuler (si j'ai bien compris). Qu'en est-il d'une constitution ? Quel est le bon verbe à utiliser ?

La constitution établit/dispose/affirme que la langue de la République est le français ?

Answer (score 4):

N'importe quoi [sauf](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/1299075/stipuler) [*stipuler*](https://www.noslangues-ourlanguages.gc.ca/fr/juridictionnaire/stipulant-stipuler.html), une impropriété courante. La constitution est la loi fondamentale. Généralement, les lois *commandent, disposent, édictent, exigent, prévoient, établissent, affirment*, etc. Tout verbe connotant l'aspect impératif convient.

---

> Éviter d'employer le terme *stipuler* à propos d'un acte juridique
> unilatéral, notamment à propos d'une loi ou d'un règlement. La loi ou
> le règlement *prévoit*, *dispose* ou *édicte*.
>
> [ Vitrine linguistique (BDL/OQLF), « [stipuler](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/1299075/stipuler) » ]
>
> [...] Avec le temps, l’aire verbale de *stipuler* s’est élargie et on
> dit depuis longtemps maintenant que le *contrat stipule*.
>
> Cependant, c’est par un abus de langage qu’on dit, commettant de ce
> fait une impropriété grossière, qu’une loi, qu’un article de loi,
> qu’un code, qu’un règlement, qu’un décret, qu’un arrêté, qu’un arrêt
> ou qu’un jugement, qui ne sont aucunement des actes contractuels,
> [stipule]. Le législateur, l’officier ministériel, le juge, n’étant
> nullement parties à des conventions, ne peuvent [stipuler]. Le juge
> statue, décide, le lieutenant-gouverneur en conseil décrète, prend des
> règlements, le législateur édicte, l’arrêt décide, la loi dispose.
>
> [ Juridictionnaire, «
> [stipulant, ante / stipuler](https://www.noslangues-ourlanguages.gc.ca/fr/juridictionnaire/stipulant-stipuler.html) » ]
>
> [...] L'emploi le plus vivant, comme pour *stipulation*, concerne les
> clauses d'un traité.
>
> [ *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sup. A. Rey,
> Robert, 2011, « stipuler » ]

---

Oui, on peut dire dans un sens plus faible qu'une disposition d'une loi vient préciser quelque chose (« stipuler »), mais vu que dans le domaine juridique « stipuler » réfère au contenu d'un acte juridique bilatéral, on introduit une confusion sémantique et une antinomie qui fait qu'il s'agit plutôt d'une impropriété ou d'une synonymie malheureuse (le premier exemple du Conseil constitutionnel dans [cette réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/54050/26366) est particulièrement éloquent à cet égard) que d'une nuance dans la presque totalité des cas. La loi commande, même dans ses précisions.

Comment: Argh --- Il va falloir que tu "lawyer up" ;-) Je t'avais donné +1, mais quelqu'un à trouver le moyen de défaire ça avec un -1 ?!

Comment: _Anytime_. Je présente deux sources concordantes, le DHLF indique que l'emploi le plus vivant de stipuler est pour les clauses d'un traité et, franchement, il s'agit d'une impropriété dont on dispose à la première année de la « license ». Cette impropriété participe d'un language qu'on veut précieux ou technique chez des non juristes ou de simples arrêtistes ou chez des juristes qui devraient retourner sur les bancs d'écoles plutôt que de se mettre un doigt dans l’œil. Cette impropriété me dérange depuis toujours. Je rejette cet emploi profane qui mélange les genres. _Lex imperat, non docet_.

Comment: « [...] une loi dispose, édicte ou statue, mais ne stipule pas » (Tancelin, _Obligations_, n° 300, p. 177). Un texte parmi d'autres sans doute, ce qui explique pourquoi le juridictionnaire classe cette [impropriété](https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/blog/la-loi-ne-stipule-pas/) dans sa sélection de [barbarismes](https://www.noslangues-ourlanguages.gc.ca/fr/juridictionnaire/barbarisme-pataques-solecisme.html).

Comment: *STIPVLARE DIABOLICVM* ;-)

Comment: ERRAREHUMANUMESTPERSEVERAREDIABOLICVM

Comment: Déchiquerons ;0 Bof, je suis peut-être dû pour retourner travailler si j'ai le temps de sauter un coche là-dessus. Normalement je chiâle parce que les gens en général voient le droit comme un truc formaliste où une virgule manquante compromet une stipulation et vicie le consentement dans son tréfonds etc. Là c'est moi qui est bien formel, mais ça me fait grincer des dents _la loi stipule_, surtout dans un monde où on se fout des normes et des règles, si il faut en plus en affaiblir légalité impérative au lexique on n'est pas sorti du bois.

Answer (score 2):

**Stipuler** dans le *Dictionnaire culturel en langue française* (extrait) :

1. Dr. Énoncer comme condition dans un contrat, un acte.
2. Énoncer comme condition expresse, faire savoir expressément. → préciser.

**Stipuler** dans le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (extrait) :

*Stipuler* a signifié en droit « contracter (une vente) par le type de contrat appelé *stipulation* » (1289) et « faire un contrat » (1489). Le verbe signifie en droit « énoncer comme condition dans un contrat » [...] et par extension « faire savoir expressément ».

**Stipuler** dans le [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/stipuler) :
A. − DR. Énoncer comme condition expresse dans un contrat, dans une convention.
B. − Cour. Faire savoir de façon impérative, expressément. Synon. *préciser, spécifier*.

Donc si le sens originel de *stipuler* est bien juridique, je stipule que le mot est désormais utilisé couramment dans un sens plus large.

Pour de ce qui est de la constitution, référons-nous aux [*Indispensables du droit constitutionnel*](https://www.editions-ellipses.fr/accueil/1195-les-indispensables-du-droit-constitutionnel-9782340013148.html)<sup>1</sup> :

> Du point de vue politique, la constitution est un acte souverain traduisant le Pacte social à la base de la société. De ce point de vue, **la constitution est un contrat**<sup>2</sup> visant à limiter le pouvoir de l’État et des gouvernants. Fruit du libéralisme politique, la constitution s’impose, à partir du XVIIIe siècle, comme l’acte fondamental destiné à préserver les libertés individuelles et nourrit une véritable doctrine politique : le constitutionnalisme.

Donc quand il est écrit que (par exemple) :

> L'article 2 de la constitution stipule entre autres : La langue de la République est le français.([Service public+](https://www.plus.transformation.gouv.fr/experiences/3128628_merci-de-respecter-la-constitution))

> l’article 89 de la Constitution stipule que « l’initiative de révision de la Constitution appartient concurremment au président de la République sur proposition du Premier ministre et aux membres du Parlement. » ([huffingtonpost.fr](https://www.huffingtonpost.fr/politique/article/ivg-dans-la-constitution-quelle-suite-apres-le-vote-historique-au-senat_213549.html))

> L'article 1 de la Constitution stipule que la France "assure l'égalité devant la loi de tous les citoyens sans distinction d'origine, de race ou de religion". ([JDD du 22/01/2016](https://www.lejdd.fr/Politique/Revision-constitutionnelle-le-PS-veut-la-suppression-du-mot-race-de-la-Constitution-769379))

> La Constitution stipule d'une part que l'Assemblée vote seule la loi, d'autre part que le président de la République désigne le président du conseil.  (Paul Reynaud, homme politique, en 1953, cité par le journal *Le Monde*)

> La Constitution stipule que « *le Premier ministre peut, après délibération du Conseil des ministres, engager la responsabilité du Gouvernement devant l'Assemblée nationale sur le vote d'un projet de loi de finances* ... (Site de [TV5monde](https://information.tv5monde.com/international/reforme-des-retraites-en-france-quelles-sorties-de-crise-possibles-2174227))

le verbe *stipuler* est bien employé dans son sens premier juridique et je ne vois pas de verbe qui conviendrait mieux.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Béal-Long Julien, Chambardon Nicolas, Malblanc Matthias, Protière Guillaume, Ellipses, 2016.

<sup>2</sup> C'est moi qui souligne.</sub>

Comment: J'allais écrire l'inverse ^^ La loi dispose, un article dispose, quand c'est "un article de la constitution" c'est toujours "dispose". Et la constitution peut être vue comme une loi (différent de *la* loi), c'est d'ailleurs comme ça que wikipédia le définit ( "*Une constitution est une loi fondamentale qui fixe l'organisation et le fonctionnement d'un [...] État*")

Comment: D'ailleurs j'ai trouvé un site du gouvernement qui dit "la constitution dispose" : https://www.collectivites-locales.gouv.fr/institutions/le-cadre-constitutionnel-general-issu-des-articles-72-73-et-74-de-la-constitution . Ton lien Service Public pointe sur un commentaire d'un usager, et le deuxième venant du Huffington Post, je suis pas surpris de voir ce genre d'erreur. Un article stipule toujours donc je ne pense pas que ces exemples soient à retenir.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat J'ai pris deux exemples au hasard mais tu peux en trouver énormément d'autres, par ailleurs. Et pourquoi devrait-on ignorer ce que dit un citoyen lambda ? Je fais partie de ceux qui disent que c'est aussi le peuple qui fait la langue. Je ne suis pas d'accord pour dire que la constitution est « une loi », comme l'a dit [Georges Vedel](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georges_Vedel) (professeur de droit public) : « Juridiquement, la constitution peut être définie « comme l’ensemble des règles de droit les plus importantes de l’État »

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Puisque tu cites Wikipedia tu peux aussi y trouver, entre autres, cette phrase : *en France (République à régime semi-présidentiel) la constitution stipule que la « souveraineté nationale appartient au peuple qui l'exerce par ses représentants et par la voie du référendum. »*

Comment: un article dispose*, pardon.

Comment: Je suis aussi du côté "l'usage fait loi" de manière générale la langue appartient à ses locuteurs et pas à une quelconque autorité, mais là la question porte sur un "bon usage" et je pense qu'il faut répondre ce qui est considéré comme "la forme correcte" (qu'on souhaite s'y plier ou non). Rien de mal à utiliser "stipuler" dans le langage courant, mais je suis pas sûr que ce soit "la forme correcte".

Answer (score 0):

[Une loi dispose, un article dispose](https://novataux.com/un-article-dispose/), mais pour la constitution c'est plus compliqué.

Si on cherche "la constitution stipule" et "la constitution dispose" sur google (avec les guillemets), on trouve des résultats pour les deux, venant de senat.fr, assemblee-nationale.fr, conseil-constitutionnel.fr etc.

Exemples :

> La Constitution stipule que ce droit est absolu et inaliénable et l'article 45 précise qu'il ne peut en aucun cas être restreint. ([conseil-constitutionnel.fr](https://www.conseil-constitutionnel.fr/nouveaux-cahiers-du-conseil-constitutionnel/textes-a-l-appui-selection-de-decisions-de-la-cour-constitutionnelle-d-armenie))

> La Constitution dispose cependant que, pour certains textes, le peuple peut être appelé à voter directement la loi par voie de référendum. ([assemblee-nationale.fr](https://www.assemblee-nationale.fr/connaissance/vote_loi.asp))

Avec "l'article" :

> L'article 72-2 alinéa 2 de la Constitution dispose que « les collectivités territoriales peuvent recevoir tout ou partie du produit des impositions de toutes natures. La loi peut les autoriser à en fixer l'assiette et le taux dans les limites qu'elle détermine ». ([conseil-constitutionnel.fr](https://www.conseil-constitutionnel.fr/nouveaux-cahiers-du-conseil-constitutionnel/la-constitution-et-les-finances-locales))

> L'article 29-2 de la Constitution stipule : " L'âge requis pour l'exercice du droit de vote est celui qui aura obtenu la majorité des voix à un référendum organisé aux termes de la loi du 25 mars 1953." ([senat.fr](https://www.senat.fr/lc/lc4/lc42.html))

Je ne dis pas qu'un des termes n'est pas préférable, mais au minimum l'usage hésite, même les personnes dont c'est le métier. Même si il existe des exemples, selon moi "*l'article stipule*" est fautif, c'est celui que j'ai eu le plus de mal à trouver dans des contextes officiels (ici c'est dans une traduction de la constitution danoise il me semble).

Quand on utilise directement "*la constitution <verbe>*", les deux sont utilisés. J'aurais tendance à penser que seul l'un des deux est correct mais je ne saurais pas me prononcer sur lequel.

Comment: Y'a une provision de la constitution qui stipule clairement que c'est la prison direct si tu te plantes et que tu utilises le mot incorrect.